# DISTINCT for large table

Tags: sql, ssms

I have got a very large table and in one column I have some strings like `TypeA`, `TypeB`, etc I would like to do a query with `CASE` operator using that column

```
CASE WHEN col1 = 'TypeA' Then '25'
     WHEN col1 = 'TypeB' Then '28'
    ...
     WHEN col1 = '????' Then '15'
END
```

but I do not know how many unique values that column has and what are they (they are words/sentences up to 3 words).
I know I could find those unique values by

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1 FROM table1
```

or

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 GROUP BY col1
```

but due to the size of table it's executing endlessly

Can I do it in efficient way? I want to find all unique values just from 1 column

Comment: Do `select distinct col1 into #temptable...` and then work with the results.

Answer (score 1):

It seems one should better **create a table with unique values**. Then you can join on that table, and the value domain is open-ended. You can then replace the field with a reference to the value table.

As there does not seem to exist an index on `col1` DISTINCT on the original table is slow. Have an index / primary key on the `col1` of the value table.